# Manipulate Table column width with button click by passing parameter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie to front-end development. I need to display my data in an HTML `<table>` (fixed `<td>` width and height).
If the data exceeds the `<td>` width, I would like to provide a button to expand the width of `<td>`.

I am using a large number of table columns, and thus am not using, nor plan to maintain, a unique `id` for each  element, so `getElementById` isn't an option.

My question is, can I pass a `<td>` object to `onclick()` event? Or, if not, is there any other way of doing it?

My code is posted below:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        <!-- Manipulate the object width-->
    }
</script>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <!-- Any way to pass td object to Function()-->
        <button onclick= "Function()">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: You can pass the clicked element by using `onclick="Function(this)"`

Comment: I tried it but this passed object of the button but not table column

Comment: `el.parentElement` should give you the td element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should explain how to pass the current element to a function.

```js
  function myFunction(el) {
    var tdEl = el.parentElement;
    tdEl.style.width = tdEl.style.width == "100px" ? "200px" : "100px" ;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Test1</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width:100px">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Test2</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width:100px">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Test3</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As BlackPearl suggested you can access the td element from the button

```
    <script>
    function myFunction(target)
    {
        var td = target.parentElement;
        td.style.width = "300px";
    }
</script>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <!-- Any way to pass td object to Function()-->
        <button onclick= "Function(this)">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```